# How can Create Unobtrusive AJAX in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Before Submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to disable the button when I send the ajax request. the only thing that is triggered is the console.log. I thought that I can achive that if I use the beforeSubmit option in ajax but Unobtrusive AJAX doesn't give that option. Is there any way that I can achieve that?

Thank you very much in advance

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("OrderDetails",
                       "Checkout",
                       null,
                       new AjaxOptions
                       {
                           HttpMethod = "POST",
                           UpdateTargetId = "Checkout",
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                           OnBegin = "disableBtnBegin()",
                           OnSuccess = "disableBtnSuccess()",
                           OnFailure = "disableBtnFailure()",
                           LoadingElementId = "loaderSubmit"
                       },
                       new { id = "OrderDetailsForm" }))
{
    

    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
           
            <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check row">
                    <div class="check-bx-wrapper col-12">
                        <div class="input-check">
                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="shippingAddressGroup" class="company-account-form row shipping_address w-100">
               
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-primary" id="nextStepBtn">
                    <span id="loaderSubmit" class="loader-hidden lds-dual-ring" style="display: none;"></span>
                
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


    <script>

        function disableBtnBegin() {

            console.log("on begin");
  
            var nextBtn = $('#nextStepBtn');
        
            nextBtn.prop("disabled", true);

        }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with same code as you shared, which work well on my side, the button could be disabled as expected.

[image]

You can inspect the actual html source of that button in browser, and check if `disabled` attribute has been set.

[image]

And you can try the following code snippet, then check if it works.

```
$('#nextStepBtn').attr("disabled", true);
```

Besides, please recheck if you have installed/included **jQuery unobtrusive ajax** client library in your project and add the reference of the required jQuery libraries.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```